# How to validate that function is returning integers with enough randomness

Tags: c

I am in development of a header file that has multiple functions

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1024

void int2str(int num, char *s)
{
    sprintf(s, "%d", num);
}



// takes a pointer to an integer 
void randNum(int *ptr)
{
    char str[MAX];
    srand(time(0));
    int tmp = rand();
    int2str(tmp, str);
    printf("%d [%c]\n", tmp, str[strlen(str)-1]);
    const char c = str[strlen(str)-1];  
    *ptr = atoi(&c);
}
```

My question is how do I make sure that my function returns random numbers with enough randomness so that I am able to use it for different stuff including encryption
When I used the header file to generate a 100 random numbers I got the same number for more than one time and sometimes for more than three times is this normal or is the implementation for such a function poor

Comment: Apart from `rand()` not being very random, you should call `srand(time(0));` once, at the start of the program. As it is now, if you call `randNum()` more often than once per second, you'll get the same number. Aside: don't put functions (or variables) into a header file - it's for declarations.

Comment: where should I declare functions using them in the `main.c` creates a big file that causes headache to scroll up and down to find anything

Comment: Function definitions go in a .c file, function declarations go in a .h file. If the main file is too big to manage, create another module and link it. That's not the main problem though: it was an "aside".

Comment: `sprintf(s, "%d", num);` that is an overkill :)

Comment: "I got the same number for more than one time" - bound to happen even after fixing the problems noted above , otherwise it cannot possibly be 'random', as previous outcomes will dictate future results (one common anti-definition of random)  [Never gets old](https://xkcd.com/221/). Regardless, for crypto, random is *hard*, and `rand` is a *terrible* choice even if you fix the aforementioned locality of your `srand`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I make sure that my function returns random numbers with enough randomness

You can run statistical tests. This is sufficient for some applications, but not all.

> different stuff including encryption

If your code fails statistical tests, it's definitely bad for encryption, or pretty much any purpose related to cryptography or more generally to security. But even if your code passes statistical tests, it can be very bad for cryptography.

It is impossible to determine whether a random generator is good for encryption by looking only at its output. For example, if you take a good cryptographic-strength random generator and you don't protect its internal state from snooping, that makes it unsuitable. You can't tell whether the internal state is protected by looking only at the outputs. You have to review its code, understand the algorithms that it uses, and also understand the context in which it runs.

> ```
> srand(time(0));
> int tmp = rand();
> ```

`rand()` in the C standard library is not suitable for cryptography. Just this snippet has three catastrophic defects.

- `rand()` on all the platforms I've ever seen is an algorithm chosen for speed, not for security. Given a moderate number of outputs, it's possible to calculate the others.
- Even if a platform used a cryptographic random generator algorithm for `rand()`, the seed set by `srand(time())` is easy to find (you just need to know when the generator was seeded), so an adversary could simply reproduce the calculation.
- Even if the adversary was not able to guess the seed, `int` is typically no more than 32 bits, so it's easy to brute-force all possible seeds.

For any purpose that might be related to cryptography or security, use the random generator provided by your operating system or by a cryptographic library, for example [`BCryptGenRandom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom) on Windows, [`/dev/urandom`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=urandom&apropos=0&sektion=4) on most Unix variants including Linux and macOS, etc.

Comment: Interesting, so is it possible to write code that generates random values without using `srand`,`rand` or the random generator provided by the system so that I have  a random cross platform number generator

Comment: @manuel Without the help of the operating system, you can write a CSPRNG (look it up). You need the operating system to seed it.

Answer (score 2):

To determine if a function is returning *uniformly-distributed* numbers, you simply call it a gazillion times and histogram the results.

Simply being uniformly-distributed is not enough for proper encryption and Monte-Carlo simulations. You should absolutely ***not*** be doing it with `rand()` and friends. You need an entirely different class of RNG: a **Cryptographically-Secure PRNG**, or CSPRNG.

I wrote a little library to make it easy to access your OS’s [CSPRNG](https://github.com/Duthomhas/CSPRNG). You can also google around the “Blum Blum Shub” or “Yarrow” algorithms if you would prefer to use them. They pass all the hard cryptographic test suites. However:

##### Don’t do encryption by yourself

You’ll get it wrong. Really. You should use a library for cryptographic purposes. Because it is tricky!

(I just know how to get good random numbers. I haven’t messed with encryption.)

Comment: For Monte-Carlo simulation you usually wouldn't use a cryptographically-secure generator (although `rand` is still likely a bad choice).

Comment: I want to write my own lib for encryption just to learn the different concepts around that subject

Comment: @user17732522 For Monte-Carlo you need a CPRNG, though. But yeah.

Comment: @manuel Random generation is one of the trickiest parts of cryptography. You're not going to reach a point where you can learn by implementing it without having first read about cryptography and security and gotten some practical experience implementing cryptography. (Source: I'm a professional cryptography implementer.) So don't start with that. I suggest starting with hashes, then moving to authentication, then to encryption, then to key derivation. At that point, _pseudo_-random generation will be within your reach.

Comment: @manuel You have a lot of reading ahead of you. Alas, it has been ages since I studied the subject, and so I have no good books or websites to recommend to you. Perhaps someone else will?

Comment: @Dúthomhas i have this one book called Network security essentials by william stallings just started reading it

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I have repeatedly found that people tend to believe that cryptography is something available to the everyman programmer, and don’t believe me when I say they haven’t the foggiest idea how deep the rabbit hole they are standing over goes.